# ModalNavigationDrawer content not taking required with - Jetpack Compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, material3

```
ModalNavigationDrawer(
        drawerState = sideBarDrawerState,
        drawerContent = {
            SideBar(
                drawerState = sideBarDrawerState,
                navController = navController,
            )
        }
    ) {}
```

above is my modal drawer and below is the drawer content, some how the drawer content doesn't take my required width, why?

```
ModalDrawerSheet() {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxHeight()
                .fillMaxWidth(0.85f)
)
```

Comment: What is the expectation and the observed UI? Add some screenshots for reference.